# SQL Query with Arithmetic Sub-Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I have a simple MYSQL table with about 5 columns or so. The row size of the table changes quite frequently.

One of these columns is named `has_error`, and is a column that has a value of either `1` or `0`.

I want to create a single SQL query that will be the equivalent of the following simple equation:

(Number of rows with `has_error = 1`/Total number of rows in table) * 100

I can create the individual SQL queries (see below), but not sure how to put it all together.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_number_of_rows FROM my_table
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_rows_with_errors FROM My_table WHERE has_error = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy because you can just use `avg(has_error)`:

```
SELECT AVG(has_error) * 100
FROM My_table;
```

Comment: Doh! Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks.